# Creating a logical circuit

Tags: logic, circuits

**Task**:
Design a 2 bit comparator.

Input: 2x 2 bit (I take it as 2 2-bit values, let them be unsigned for simplicity) 
Output: 1 if result input1>input2 is true, 0 otherwise

Develop truth table and derive circuits.

**The problem**: I'm completely new to this so I have not even a idea where where to look for the lighthouse.

**The question**: I'M NOT LOOKING FOR COMPLETE SOLUTION, instead I'm looking for a guidance through topics/materials which I should check to be able to solve it myself.

**Done so far**: I started with understanding logical gates and those seem to be pretty straight forward.

P.S.: Purpose of posting this question is to boost the speed with which I will get to the actual solution.

**SOLUTION:**
f(A,B,C,D) = !AB!C!D + A!C + ABC!D. (! - used for negation or NOR, ABC notations means A AND B AND C). I had three adjacent rectangles two of which were of unit cell size and one of 4 cells size (one cell was actually far away, but there's this toroidally connection property, not sure about terminology). A and B are MSD and LSD of the first number respectfully and B and C are same for second number. *As for the circuit image:* sorry folks my hand drawing requires strong mental stability.

Comment: Do you know what a truth table is? Also, curious of how you are doing a reasonably advanced problem when you had to start from understanding what logic gates are?

Comment: @Paresh, well I'm not completely completely new :-). Surely I know what truth table is. Just devoured Karnaugh map article and ready to move on.

Comment: Aah, that should make things easier. In that case, where exactly are you having trouble? For example, did you form the truth table? If yes, did you manage to get a boolean expression from it?

Comment: @Paresh, I went straight to Karnaugh map and got next: f(ABCD)=!AB!C!D + A!C + ABC!D. (! - used for negation or NOR, ABC notations means A AND B AND C). I had three adjusent rectangles two of which were of unit cell size and one of 4 cells size (one cell was actually far away, but there's this toroidally connection property, not sure about terminology). A and B are MSD and LSD of the first number respectfully and B and C are same for second number. This problem seems to be almost the same as here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karnaugh_map#Example

Comment: Well, your expression is correct (assuming AB is input1 and CD is input2, and A and C are both the most significant bits). Which means you are almost done! You might want to go through some of the links I provided, but it seems to me that you are already well set - and definitely not new as your question suggests! :)

Comment: @Paresh, the circuit looks is a bit bulky, but this was a really easy task if I can solve it in 1.5 hours from ground 0. :-) I am indeed completely new to it, I just knew some of that and some of this especially about Boolean logic part. Anyway, thanks for help as you did lighten the lighthouse. ;-)

Comment: Glad I could help! Just a correction: the '!' is for a NOT gate, not a NOR gate. A NOR gate is something different (NOT gate in series with a OR gate).

Comment: @Paresh, yeah, that was a typo, NOR results in same as an inverted result of an OR gate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, as the problem asks you to make a truth table, you should first make one (this is generally a good idea even if not asked explicitly). For your question, you can say assign two bits to input1, say $a$ and $b$, and two bits to the input2, say $x$ and $y$. Then you might say that if $a = 1$ and $b = 0$, input 1 is $2$.

Once you have the truth table (4 inputs, one output), you can get the corresponding boolean expression from the truth table in "sum-of-products" form. Basically, suppose for every entry where the output is 1, you form a "min-term" of the inputs. For example, say for 2 inputs $p$ and $q$, if output is $1$ when $p=1$ and $q = 0$, the min-term would be $p\bar{q}$. Get these min-terms for all inputs where the output is 1, and add them/OR-them together. This is because the output is 1 if and only if any one min-terms is true. You can read more [here](http://www.allaboutcircuits.com/vol_4/chpt_7/9.html) or [here](http://www.usna.edu/EE/ec262/notes/05-Boolean%20Algebra%20student%20version.pdf) or [here](http://www.eng.uah.edu/~hitedw/EE100/Chapter7/EE100CH7.pdf).

Now, once you have the boolean expression, you might want to minimize it - implement the logic using fewer gates. This is not asked in your question, but you might want to do it anyways. Karnaugh map technique, which you seem to already have read, is one technique. There is another called the [Quine-McCluskey](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quine%E2%80%93McCluskey_algorithm) algorithm.

Once you have the boolean expression, you can generate the corresponding circuit mechanically. So, for each min-term, implement it using AND gates, and NOT gates. Connect all these to the input of a OR gate. For example, for something like $p\bar{q} + \bar{p}q$, $p\bar{q}$ means $p$ **AND** (**NOT** $q$). Do the same for the other min-term, and give them to the input of an OR gate. The above links also provide information and examples about this.

As for speed, you'll get faster with practice!

Answer (score 1):

There is a methodology for implementing logical [Combinational circuit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinational_logic)

suppose your Boolean function is $f(x_1,x_2,...,x_n)=(y_1,y_2,...,y_m)$ in which $x_i,y_i \in \{0,1\}$

1) First make a [Truth Table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truth_table)

2) Then write each $y_j$ base on $(x_1, x_2,..., x_n)$ using [CNF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunctive_normal_form) or [DNF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjunctive_normal_form)

3) Then use [Quine-McCluskey](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quine%E2%80%93McCluskey_algorithm) for function minimization.